# Play Sound file without importing winmm.dll or microsoft.visualbasic.dll

Tags: .net, linux, delphi, wav, delphi-prism

I am writing a program using Delphi prism. The goal is to be able run on windows and linux (mono) from the same project. So, at this point I need to have a way of playing a sound file for windows and linux(mono) without having to import winmm.dll or microsoft.visualbasic.dll.

Since I need this to work on mono also, I don't want to use visualbasic.dll. In the past, it gave me all kinds of issues.

Are there ways to play sound file without using these dll files?

**UPDATE**

No matter how the soundplayer is instantiated and used, it always works fine under windows OS, whereas on Linux under mono it sometimes plays and other times it just won't play at all.

**First Version:**

```
  var thesound := new SoundPlayer;

  if Environment.OSVersion.Platform = Environment.OSVersion.Platform.Unix then
    thesound.SoundLocation := '/sounds/Alarms.wav'
  else
    thesound.SoundLocation:='\sounds\Alarms.wav';

  thesound.Load;
  thesound.PlayLooping;
```

**Second Version**

```
var sp := new SoundPlayer(new FileStream("/sounds/Alarms.wav", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read));
sp.PlayLooping;
```

Comment: A lot of the information they have online about playing sound file is in relation to microsoft dll files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`System.Media.SoundPlayer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.media.soundplayer.aspx). This is implemented by Mono.

Comment: Hi, I have implemented the SoundPlayer in my program but didn't test it yet for my program has other compiler errors, which I am working through. Maybe I should write a sample program and test it. Then, I will accept your answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @ David, One of the thing I noticed since I started to write program for Linux or Mono from way back is that Linux or Mono environment is nothing like Windows and this is why it is very secure. Thus, anything you write for them, you need to make sure you take every steps and execute all that is necessary to accomplish what you need to do. The reason sound files played and other times it didn't was not because there was something wrong with the code. When you start something in Linux it has to end as well or it will be stuck in that mode and will not let you start it up again i.e. serial port.

Comment: @digitalanalog Windows and Linux are very different it's true. Mono and .net are not. Linux is not inherently more secure than modern Windows.

Comment: "Linux is not inherently more secure than modern Windows." I strongly doubt that and it is another topic all together. I can tell you how and why, but there is not enough space in the comment section. :)

Comment: Security researchers find as many vulns in Linux as in Windows.

Comment: @ David, it depends on who you ask. You really have to look at who is funding the research or study. If Microsoft funding it, then the study or the research findings will favor Microsoft of course and if it is Linux community, then it will favor the Linux community.

Comment: US-CERT have pretty good statistics. Have a read up on the sorry story of the Debian SSH bug and then you won't be so enamoured with Linux.